# Congruence of positive semi-definite matrices to identity matrix

Tags: modular-arithmetic, positive-semidefinite

Let $A$ be a positive semi-definite matrix. I want to know if $A$
is congruent to $I_{n}$ which is a $n$ by $n$ identity matrix. Here, Congruence means there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such
that $I_{n}=PAP^{T}$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition your condition can also be written as $A=P^{-1}(P^{T})^{-1}$

Comment: Thanks for comment! Which part of the link should I see?

Comment: Look at the statement.

Comment: How could it be like that? Please explain more.

Comment: If $A$ is diag(1,0), then $A$ is positive semi-definite but can't be written like that.

Comment: Please read the statement in link... It works for  Hermitian positive-definite matrix.

Comment: But my question is for Positive semi-definite matrices.

Comment: I know... But you atleast have a proof for positive definite matrix right ... Try to follow the same ideas and see where it fails...

Comment: From the equation $PAP^T=I$, it is clear that $A$ has to be invertible. So you cannot have $0$ eigenvalues...Hence all eigen values has to be $>0$.

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much!